# Left and right trim string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string format that is of this format `{"message ":"System: you are now connected as ghi"}`

I want to trim it such that I get this `System: you are now connected as user` as final string.
I guess in JS we cannot trim a string and we can only trim white spaces so how do I get this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring is for "trimming", but it looks like you'd need to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) a part of the string.

Comment: *"I guess in JS we cannot trim a string and we can only trim white spaces"* You can remove any part of a string at all. But it seems likely here that you want to parse the string (`JSON.parse(yourString)`) and use the resulting object's `message` property. (I'm assuming the space in `"message "` in your question is a typo in the question, not actually present in the JSON.)

Comment: then he should have written it as `'{"message ":"System: you are now connected as ghi"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Your KEY has a trailing space

```js
const message = JSON.parse(`{"message ":"System: you are now connected as ghi"}`)["message "]

console.log(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access the message with spaced key you can do as follow:

```js
const str = '{"message ":"System: you are now connected as ghi"}'

const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj["message "])
```

if you are trying to remove the space out of the keys of your object you can do as follow:

```js
const str = '{"message ":"System: you are now connected as ghi"}'

const obj = JSON.parse(str);

Object.keys(obj).filter(entry => entry !== entry.trim())
                .forEach(entry => {
                     const trimmedEntry = entry.trim();
                     obj[trimmedEntry] = obj[entry];
                     delete obj[entry];
                 })
console.log(obj)
```